# php and MySQL beginner accepting user input, modifying a database, and returning values

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I will preface this question with the fact that I have only six weeks of experience with PHP and only two weeks of experience with MySQL. I am attempting to create a demonstration website that will accept user input for software bugs. The forms accept user input and, by using PHP , I am connecting to a local SQL database I have established. The database "bugs" has been established, as has the table of bugDetails to include the fields of "version", "hardware", "os", and "description". I have built out a PHP  document to outline the form and pass the information to the SQL database. I have also created two include files to protect the database passwords, as well as address the magic quotes issue. For the life of me, I cannot get the code to work and I am unsure as to why. Any assistance is much appreciated. Here is my code:

bugs.php

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <title>Submit a bug</title> 
    <style>
      input {
         display: inline;
         width: auto;
         text-align: left;
      } 
    </style>
   </head>
  <body>

    Please enter info about the issue you have encounted:
    <form id="add_rec" name="add_record" method="post"
      action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
      <div>
        <label for="version">Software Version:</label>
        <input name="version" type="text" id="version" 
          size="128" 
          maxlength="127" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="hardware">Hardware Used: </label>
        <input name="hardware" type="text" id="hardware" 
          size="128" 
          maxlength="127" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="os">Operating System: </label>
        <input name="os" type="text" id="os" size="128" 
          maxlength="127" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="description">Describe the Issue: </label>
        <input name="description" type="text" id="description" size="4000" 
          maxlength="3999" />
      </div>
    </form>


    <?php

      // Process data from the form 
      if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
        include 'fix_magic_quotes.php';
        include 'open_db.php';

        $version = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, 
          $_POST['version']);
        $hardware = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, 
          $_POST['hardware']);
        $os = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, 
          $_POST['os']);
        $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['description']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO bugDetails SET
            version = '$version',
            hardware = '$hardware',
            os = $os,
            description ='$description',

        if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
          $output = 'Could not submit your issue to table: ' . 
            mysqli_error($link);
          include 'output.php';
          exit();
        }
        $output = 'Your issue has been successfully logged to table:';
        include 'output.php';
      }  // end if
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

open_db.php

```
<?php
  // Log into MySQL
  $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'andrew', 'Heruka123!');
  if (!$link){
    $output = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
    include 'output.php';
    exit();
  }
  // Set database encoding
  if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8')){
    $output = 'Unable to set database connection encoding.';
    include 'output.php';
    exit();
  } 
  // Open the database
  if (!mysqli_select_db($link, 'bugs')){
    $output = 'Unable to locate the joke database.';
    include 'output.php';
    exit();
  }
  // No errors found so inform user
  $output = 'Database connection established.';
  include 'output.php';
?>
```

fix_magic_quotes.php

```
<?php
   // Fix Magic Quotes Problem
   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        function stripslashes_deep($value)  {
       $value = is_array($value) ?
              array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
              stripslashes($value);

       return $value;
        }// end function 

     $_POST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_POST);
     $_GET = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_GET);
     $_COOKIE = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_COOKIE);
     $_REQUEST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST);
   }// end if
?>
```

Comment: Your insert query has update syntax. It is also incomplete and reveals syntax errors. That is the first thing I was able to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your bugs.php, your PHP is not complete. You did not close your assignment of `$sql` with a `";`. The SQL is not correct syntax for `INSERT`:

```
<?php
// Process data from the form 
if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
    include 'fix_magic_quotes.php';
    include 'open_db.php';

    $version = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['version']);
    $hardware = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['hardware']);
    $os = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['os']);
    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['description']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO bugDetails (version, hardware, os, description) VALUES ('$version', '$hardware', $os, '$description');";
    if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        $output = 'Could not submit your issue to table: ' . 
        mysqli_error($link);
        include 'output.php';
        mysqli_close($link);
        exit();
    }
    $output = 'Your issue has been successfully logged to table:';
    include 'output.php';
}  // end if
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semicolon(;) in your sql statement please change your current sql statement `$sql = "INSERT INTO bugDetails SET version = $version', hardware = '$hardware',  os = $os, description ='$description',` into this one `$sql = "INSERT INTO bugDetails SET version = $version', hardware = '$hardware',  os = $os, description ='$description';` in place of comma (,) put semicolon (;)

Thank you